# Why do some operators change their type when they are assigned?

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

When I ask the type of the + operator it is as you would expect

```
Prelude> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

When I assign the operator to a variable then the type signatures changes

```
Prelude> let x = (+)
Prelude> :t x
x :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

Why would the type of an operator change when it is assigned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the "dreaded monomorphism restriction". Essentially, when you define a

1. new top-level name, that
2. doesn't look like a function definition

then, by default, Haskell tries to be smart and pick a less-than-entirely general type for it. The reasons were originally to make Haskell easier to use (without it it's perhaps easier to write programs with ambiguous types), but more recently it seems to just trip everyone up since it's very unexpected behavior.

The resolution?

1. Use GHC 7.8. After version 7.8, GHCi sessions automatically...
2. Use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction, which turns off this behavior, or
3. Provide a type annotation like

   ```
   let { x :: Num a => a -> a -> a; x = (+) }
   ```

In normal Haskell code, method (3) is most highly recommended. When using GHCi, (1) and (2) are more convenient.

Comment: I always have `:set +m` in GHCi for multi line input, I find it a lot more convenient than using braces on lets and other statements.

Comment: GHC 7.8 is hard to get.

Comment: In GHCi the type annotation could also be written as `let y = (+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, which might be preferable.